# Не уверен в пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Пример: "Ну и то, что она была симпатичной девушкой тоже не помешало".

Вопрос: нужна ли запятая после "девушкой"?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится:

**Ну и то, что она была симпатичной девушкой, тоже не помешало.**

Сложноподчиненное предложения с придаточным изъяснительным. ТО ― указательное местоимение, ЧТО ― союз.

Comment: Большое мерси Jasmin. Я сложноподчинённые предложения, кажись, прогулял в школе.